# Ethernet Network is disabled in 14.04LTS

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet

When I first used Ubuntu 14.04LTS, I could use the ethernet network option in the network menubar to connect with lan, use the ftp server or browse another pc to share anything. I just need to connect to the ethernet network.

Then I faced a problem. My Network icon went away and after a lot of searching on the net I was able to solve the problem.

Then I got this problem. In the network menu option, there is no "wired connection 1" option.I searched on the net, but can find no suitable solution.

So what I want is to get "Wired connection 1" back. Please see the image to understand what my problem really is.

[image: No wired connection 1]

UPD : Output of "lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2".

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
--
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [10ec:8139] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL-8100/8101L/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter [10ec:8139]
    Kernel driver in use: 8139too
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A2` terminal command.

Comment: I have updated as u say ...

Answer (score 0):

Select "Edit Connections...", and rename the one you want (presumably the first one) to "Wired connection 1".

Comment: In edit connections the panel is like this http://postimg.org/image/b5hnkefqf/ if i add a ethernet connection from here, it won't work.              Note: IUT is my DSL connection by which I connect to Internet.